# Accepted two conditional job offers with same background check company

Tags: job-offer, background-check, employer

I Accepted two conditional job offers from two large investment banks. Both of these companies use the same background check company (First Advantage)

Is there a risk the background check company tells one company that I have accepted an offer from another company?

Comment: How would they know? Why would they care?

Comment: Background check companies operate under fairly strict confidentiality agreements, both with their employer clients and with the individuals they are checking on. You should review your paperwork and determine if you've signed something that gave them permission to use your data in a certain way.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Because they are conditional?

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and accept conditional job offers, until you have an unconditional and confirmed offer in hand.

A conditional job offer is **not** a guaranteed one  - there is no reason to consider it as one, most likely the other party (the company offering the job) is not.

However, once you have accepted an unconditional offer and have it signed and sealed, you should not be accepting any more offers and communicate cancellation to any outstanding conditional offers.

That said, background checks are considered very sensitive process, and unless it is actually related to the process, the identity of the person undergoing the check is not revealed to anyone in any matter. Only the results are shared with the organization requesting for the check.

And moreover, any conditional job offer that you have today is usually not part of a background check anyways, it's about the previous engagements, if at all.

Answer (score -1):

> I there a risk the background check company tells one company that I have accepted an offer from another company?

There is always a risk depending on how extensive of a background check either of the companies have asked the background check company to perform.  To prevent such incidents in the future, you should not simultaneously accept multiple job offers.  You could potentially lose both offers if the companies are aware of what you have done.

Comment: The last time I accepted a conditional job offer, I kept looking.  I found and accepted an unconditional job offer.  The funding ran out and the conditional job offer was withdrawn.  If they want you, they need to pay you - otherwise keep looking (and possibly accepting).  Conditional offers mean nothing.